# (node:15867) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint

Whenever I open/save *any* of my files ESLint gives me a list of errors such as:

```
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:15900) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

From my reading on this topic I assume that there is a dependency somewhere that isn't playing along, so here is package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "advanced-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Advanced React",
  "main": "lib/server.js",
  "repository": "jscomplete/advanced-react",
  "author": "Samer Buna",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pm2 start lib/server.js --watch --interpreter babel-node",
    "webpack": "webpack -wd"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "pm2": "^2.4.6",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

And my .eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  "parser": 'babel-eslint',
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", 'plugin:json/recommended'],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [ "react" ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": ["off"],
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["error","unix"],
    "quotes": ["error","single"],
    "semi": ["error","always"],
    "no-console": ["warn", { "allow": ["info", "error"] }]
  }
};
```

Alternatively, [here](https://github.com/jscomplete/advanced-react/tree/c62def5ddc06585c2bd8f097719811ca1ed7aaee) is where I pulled my files from. I'm running node v14.10.0. Does anyone know why I might be getting the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you need to downgrade your `nodejs` to v12. Or you can use `node --no-warnings`.

Comment: Adding `node --no-warnings` will just hide the error message, not fix it